# Read Images From Emulator sdcard folder -Android

Tags: android, gridview, android-emulator, android-sdcard

I attempt in my app to read images from sdcard folder. However, In tablet device the task done with no errors, it lists all images on folder in Gridview, BUT in Emulator, just empty Gridview list appear, although the folder and pictures exist on Emulator sdcard as you see in picture below?!

[image]

Class that used to create folder and read pictures:

**Utils Code:**

```
package com.example.imageslider.helper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.classes.DBItems;
import com.example.classes.ProjectEngine;
import com.example.diwansalesorder.MainScreen;
import com.example.diwansalesorder.R;
import com.example.imageslider.GridViewActivity;

public class Utils {

    private final Context _context;
    ArrayList<String> allData = new ArrayList<String>();
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ArrayList<String> filePaths;
    File sdCard, directory;
    File[] listFiles;

    // constructor
    public Utils(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
    }

    /*
     * Reading file paths from SDCard
     */
    public ArrayList<String> getFilePaths() {
        filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
        boolean success = true; // to check if directory created ot not
        readAllItems();
        sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/DiwanAppPictures");

        if (!directory.exists()) {
            success = directory.mkdirs();
        }
        if (success) {
            // check for directory
            if (directory.isDirectory()) {
                // getting list of file paths
                listFiles = directory.listFiles();
                // Check for count
                if (listFiles.length > 0) {
                    new LoadAllPictures().execute();

                } else {
                    new LoadAllPictures2().execute();

                }

            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);
                alert.setTitle("Error!");
                alert.setMessage(AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM
                        + " directory path is not valid! Please set the image directory name AppConstant.java class");
                alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                alert.show();

            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(_context,
                    " can't create " + AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM + " folder !!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent prevIntent = new Intent(_context, MainScreen.class);
            _context.startActivity(prevIntent);

        }
        return filePaths;
    }

    /*
     * Check supported file extensions
     * 
     * @returns boolean
     */
    private boolean IsSupportedFile(String filePath) {
        String ext = filePath.substring((filePath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1),
                filePath.length());

        if (AppConstant.FILE_EXTN
                .contains(ext.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())))
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

    /*
     * getting screen width
     */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public int getScreenWidth() {
        int columnWidth;
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) _context
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

        final Point point = new Point();
        try {
            display.getSize(point);
        } catch (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError ignore) { // Older device
            point.x = display.getWidth();
            point.y = display.getHeight();
        }
        columnWidth = point.x;
        return columnWidth;
    }

    // Function to read all items from data base
    private void readAllItems() {
        final DBItems dbI = new DBItems(_context);

        try {
            dbI.open();
            Cursor allTitles = dbI.getAllAccounts();
            allTitles.moveToFirst();

            do {
                String Item = allTitles.getString(1);
                String Name = allTitles.getString(2);
                String Cprice = allTitles.getString(3);
                String Ccurr = allTitles.getString(4);
                String Sprice = allTitles.getString(5);
                String Scurr = allTitles.getString(6);
                String Qnty = allTitles.getString(7);
                String IncVat = allTitles.getString(8);
                String StQnty = allTitles.getString(9);
                String MinQnty = allTitles.getString(10);
                String MaxQnty = allTitles.getString(11);
                String Class = allTitles.getString(12);
                String StkLoc = allTitles.getString(13);
                String currQnty = allTitles.getString(14);
                String VatDate = allTitles.getString(15);
                String Ttime = allTitles.getString(16);

                allData.add(Item + "!" + Name + "!" + Cprice + "!" + Ccurr
                        + "!" + Sprice + "!" + Scurr + "!" + Qnty + "!"
                        + IncVat + "!" + StQnty + "!" + MinQnty + "!" + MaxQnty
                        + "!" + Class + "!" + StkLoc + "!" + currQnty + "!"
                        + VatDate + "!" + Ttime + "");

            } while (allTitles.moveToNext());

            dbI.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            dbI.close();

        }
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllPictures2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(_context);
            pDialog.setMessage(ProjectEngine.fillDataMsg);
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Load Image from res
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < allData.size(); i++) {
                    OutputStream fOut = null;
                    File file = new File(directory,
                            allData.get(i).split("!")[0].toString() + ".jpeg");

                    if (file.exists())
                        file.delete();

                    file.createNewFile();
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    Drawable ditemp = _context.getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.nopicture);
                    Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable) ditemp).getBitmap();
                    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Log.e("saveToExternalStorage()", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Intent prevIntent = new Intent(_context, GridViewActivity.class);
            _context.startActivity(prevIntent);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllPictures extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(_context);
            pDialog.setMessage(ProjectEngine.fillDataMsg);
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // loop through all files
            for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++) {
                // get file path
                String filePath = listFiles[i].getAbsolutePath();

                // check for supported file extension
                if (IsSupportedFile(filePath)) {
                    // Add image path to array list
                    filePaths.add(filePath);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

please any help will be appropriated,

Comment: isSupportedFile() checks for a file extension but your picture filenames don't have an extension. Why are you posting so much code that is irrelevant to the problem?

Comment: no, this code is relevant to my problem please, which gets images from sdcard if exist otherwise create images with default one! mmm I don't understand your explanation please :( !

Comment: You don't know what a file extension is? Then remove the call to isSupportedFile and just add all files.

Comment: thanks my problem solved when I remove isSupportedFile() ,,

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's a problem with the path to the directory holding your pictures. Please compare the value returned by *Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()* method on your phone with the one returned on the emulator. They may be different, thus you may need to move your images accordingly.

Comment: yes, the value returned is /storage/sdcard which is correct! since the pictures folder in this directory! I don't know where is the problem, moreover I can't complete without complete this task!

Comment: Did you add all necessary permissions?

Comment: @greenapps It's not that straightforward. From the docs: "Caution: Currently, all apps have the ability to read the external storage without a special permission. However, this will change in a future release. If your app needs to read the external storage (but not write to it), then you will need to declare the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. To ensure that your app continues to work as expected, you should declare this permission now, before the change takes effect." Also, starting from API 19: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: this already done! BUT with no hope to know where is the problem yet!

Comment: thanks my problem solved when I remove isSupportedFile() ,,  @EyesClear